# jQuery subtract amount from sum of input fields when discount code entered

Tags: jquery, sum, var, attr

OK, I'm pulling my hair out over this. I have a form consisting of mainly drop-down selections and check boxes - these all have values assigned so as the user selects things, a total sum value of everything is calculated.

My last input field is a text input called 'Discount Code' I want to be able to enter a set code and that subtract a fixed amount from the sum.

Below is the script that I'm using to detect if the discount code is correct:

```
$(".apply_discount").click(function() {
if ($("input[name='discount']").val() === "DISTR50") {
 $("span").text("Validated...").show();
 $("input[name='discount']").attr("value",500.99);
 return true;
}
$("span").text("Not a valid discount code").show().fadeOut(2000);
return false;
});
```

and here is the code which calculates the sum of my inputs:

```
//iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
    //handler to trigger sum event
    $(".txt, .select, .checkbox").each(function() {
        $(this).change(function(){
            calculateSum();
        });
    });
});

function calculateSum() {
    var discount = $("input[name='discount']").attr('value');
    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $(".txt, .select, .checkbox:checked").each(function() {

        //add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }

    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    var calc_total = sum;
    $("#sum").html(calc_total.toFixed(2));
}
```

as you can see, the sum is appended to a div called #sum - I can't figure out how I subtract the value of the discount input.

you can see my code in action here: http://www.samskirrow.com/projects/distr/index3.html

Here it is in a JSfiddle (calculate mileage section doesn't work though)
http://jsfiddle.net/bZhK4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I understand what you are looking for: couldn't you change the calc sum function where you declare calc_total to be:

```
var calc_total = sum - parseFloat(discount);
```

And then make sure you update it on the apply discount function

```
$(".apply_discount").click(function() {
  if ($("input[name='discount']").val() === "DISTR50") {
  $("span").text("Validated...").show();
  $("input[name='discount']").attr("value",500.99);
  calculateSum();
  return true;
  }
  $("span").text("Not a valid discount code").show().fadeOut(2000);
  return false;
});
```

Comment: also you can use `.val()` to set the value `.val(500.99)`